# XML parsing error for amersand in CDATA section

Tags: cdata, ampersand

CDATA section is used to treat character '&' and '<' as normal text string but my XML is failing to parse due to '&' in CDATA section.

It says SAXParser exception with lex code 3 invalid character ' ' found.

Can you please suggest how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<![CDATA[xxxxxx > 0]]>
```

its that using my project CDATA TYPE. I think is useful for you.